# What kills my debian wheezy server?

Tags: debian, kill, apache2.2

I have a vServer and sporadicly it crashes. 
The last thing I see in the syslog is that the oom killer tries to kill Apache2. Then the server totally hangs and has to be reset.

It's a virtual server with 1 GB RAM. The usual load shown by htop is about 600MB.

Services are mainly a small Teamspeak3 Server and LAMP for 15 domains though very little traffic.

I guess there is some script going beserk and using up all memory. 
How can I find out?

I have munin and monit running but all they tell me that shortly before a crash lots of RAM is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do assuming you can reproduce the problem and you think its memory related:
try running something like this

```
while [[ true ]]; do
  ps -eo pid,user,args,%mem --sort %mem >> /tmp/memory
  sleep 2
done
```

After the server crash, examine /tmp/memory and see what was taking up the memory

Comment: Thanks! That might help. I cannot provoke the problem but it happens every few days by now. So I'll increase the sleep and see what happens.